# E325 Error with permission denied while deleting

Tags: linux-mint, vim

I have this message on Linux Mint:

```
325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/default/.grub.swp"
          owned by: root   dated: Fri Mar 29 17:37:00 2024
         file name: /etc/default/grub
          modified: YES
         user name: root   host name: ilugu-ThinkPad-X220
        process ID: 22737
While opening file "/etc/default/grub"
             dated: Fri Mar 29 18:02:31 2024
      NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /etc/default/grub"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/etc/default/.grub.swp"
    to avoid this message.
"/etc/default/grub" 33 lines, 1209 bytes
```

I tried to remove it,
but it always gives me the output:

```
rm /etc/default/.grub.swp

rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/default/.grub.swp'? y
rm: cannot remove '/etc/default/.grub.swp': Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you remember having edited (or only tried to edit) eh /etc/default/grub file ?

Comment: yea, i accidentally closed the terminal. But I don't know how to delete or close the opened file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo rm /etc/default/.grub.swp
```

Comment: Hey wait ! I would not have suggested that prior to recommending a review of the changes made (but not saved), could have been more or less critical somewhere ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To get help on a particular error code in the Vim editor, use the `:help` command:

```
:help 325
```

This would show you the sections from the Vim manual related to the error that you are seeing (in this case, [the section is tagged both `ATTENTION` and `E325`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_11.txt.html#E325)).

In that help text, it's pointed out that if you get this error, and it says `modified: YES`, then the file on disk is outdated, and a newer snapshot of the file was successfully saved to the `.swp` file while you were editing it.  Since the `process ID:` line does not end in the text `(still running)`, we can probably assume that the file was being edited when the editor was interrupted somehow, either by crashing or by the system rebooting.

The error message you show then gives you several alternative ways to resolve this, depending on your needs.

Assuming the editor is not currently running elsewhere with the file in question loaded, you can choose to recover the data that was never saved to the file.  You do this with the command suggested by the error message:

```bash
vim -r /etc/default/grub
```

This would restore your interrupted edit session, and you could save the file.  Since the root user owns the file (and the `.swp` file), you would likely have to run the above command using `sudo`.

The error message also says you can discard the non-saved data by deleting the file `/etc/default/.grub.swp`.  This could mean a loss of the information that you thought you had added to the file but never saved.  Note that this is a file owned by the root user, so you would likely have to use `sudo` to remove it.